# Accessing a text file in append mode through a mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

Is it possible accessing a text file through a mysql stored procedure.
I need to open a text file in append mode and insert a new line at the end of a file through that procedure

Basically I was writing a table's data by `LOAD INTO OUTFILE`. But the requirement is that after I've done that I need to give an extra newline. My current file looks like following.

`1|4700|00000036||20|5.00|20131123125826|183669|;
    2|4700|00000037||20|5.00|20131123142638|155207|;
    1|4700|00000038||20|5.00|20131123184917|663554|;
    2|4700|00000039||20|5.00|20131123191402|416464|;
    1|4700|00000040||20|2.30|20131123203542|260932|;`

After this I need to put a newline.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already found that you *can't* use `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` to append to a file. There are ways to do it using shell scripting and running the `mysql` command-line client, but you want to do it within a stored procedure, so you can't do that.

One way to do it within a stored procedure is by writing text to a special table. You can create a table that uses the **CSV** engine, and insert into it like this:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE textfile (mytext VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL) ENGINE=CSV;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.14 sec)
```

The table is stored as a CSV file, so you can read it as simple text and write to it using `INSERT` operations. To add text to it, simply insert values.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO textfile VALUES ('This is the first sentence.');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.14 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO textfile VALUES ('This is the second sentence.');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Because it's a CSV, the contents look like this (on my Linux machine):

```
[user@host]# cat /var/lib/mysql/test/textfile.CSV 
"This is the first sentence."
"This is the second sentence."
```